# how to create mail address labels

Tags: address-labels

How do you generate a list of (snail) mail address labels (for envelopes)?  I see how to generate an email list, but not a mailing address list turned into labels.

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

After searching you can choose the action "Mailing Labels" that does this. This creates a pdf file you can print.
And in the menu under 
Communication >> Label Formats
you can define the label formats you want to use.

Comment: In addition, if you need to edit the fields placed on your labels, you can do that at Administer >> Localization >> Address Settings. For most mailings I want `{contact.contact_id}` to be included in order to speed up data entry for returned mail.

Answer (score 1):

you should find an option under Actions from a search result that says "Mailing Labels". Is that all you need?